# What does Stray start tag html error mean?

Tags: html, syntax-error, element, fatal-error, systray

So I made this simple HTML code so far and it's already giving errors with the Validator! I don't understand what's wrong, can someone help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <html lang="en">
 </html>
 <title>Otsikko</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Otsikko </h1>
 <h2> Otsikko </h2>
 <p>Tekstiä</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Jotain</li>
  <li>Jotain</li>
  <li>Jotain</li>
 </ul>
 <ol>
  <li>Jotain</li>
  <li>Jotain</li>
  <li>Jotain</li>
 </ol>
 <dl> <dt>Jotain</dt>
  <dd>Jotain</dd> <dt>Jotain</dt>
 </dl>
    &auml; &ouml; &laquo; &reg;
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this HTML code?

Comment: You should put the `</html>` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of these at the end: `&auml; &ouml; &laquo; &reg;`

Move `</html>` to the end of the document (keep the opening tag where it is)

add a `<head> </head>` around your title and charset.

The `<dt>` tag should have a `<dd>` tag follow it. (First one did, second didn't)

Although not an error, for language accents such as `ä` you can use the HTML code such as `&auml;`. 
See: https://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Otsikko</title>
</head>
<h1> Otsikko </h1>
<h2> Otsikko </h2>
<p> Teksti&auml; </p>
<ul>
    <li>Jotain</li>
    <li>Jotain</li>
    <li>Jotain</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>Jotain</li>
    <li>Jotain</li>
    <li>Jotain</li>
</ol>
<dl>
    <dt>Jotain</dt>
    <dd>Jotain</dd>
    <dt>Jotain</dt>
    <dd>Jotain</dd>
</dl>
</html>
```

W3 has a good online validator:

https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yeah I know I got a lot of errors there if u try to validate this code  :(

Comment: @ZamiCoskula What are you using to validate? I don't get any errors with the HTML I posted

Comment: If you're referring to the ä not displaying, you can use `&auml;`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed most of the errors! But now it says "Error: Element dl is missing a required instance of child element dd.

From line 40, column 5; to line 40, column 9

</dt>↩    </dl>↩↩↩   

Content model for element dl:
Either:Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more dt elements followed by one or more dd elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.
Or: One or more div elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements."

Comment: @ZamiCoskula add a `<dd>something</dd>` after every `<dt>something</dt>`

Comment: Thanx! Now everything is valid! Ty for the help!

Comment: @ZamiCoskula No problem! feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you